Why does the 68000 have Immediate addressing modes for byte-width instructions?
Motorola's 68000 has an instruction like ori.b #immediate, d0. This particular instruction is encoded as all zeroes, followed by a full 16 bits encoding an 8-bit immediate value. The instruction word has to be followed by a 16-bit word, of course, since 8 would throw off the alignment of the instruction stream.
If we look at the size field of this instruction, bits 7 and 6, it's 00, for byte. Similarly, the ori #something, ccr instruction has 00 in the size field, since the immediate value logically can't be longer than 5 bits (wasting a full 11 bits in the instruction stream!). And one more point of comparison is the ori #something, sr instruction, which in the size field has 01, for word.
I've checked that the same story holds for other similar groups of instructions, like andi, eori, and movei, and probably others.
Are there cases where these 8-bit immediate values are not equivalent to some 16-bit immediate value? If not, why bother encoding these instructions?
Leaving out this mode would have obviated the need for a byte-sized immediate, which means the two remaining values for size, "word" and "long", can be encoded in a single bit, which saves a bit in the instruction word. As far as I see, the 68000 is a rather CISCy design: complex variable-length instructions, lots of addressing modes, etc. It seems like excluding a pointless 8-bit immediate value would be worth doing, so I feel like there's something I'm overlooking.

An 8-bit immediate leaves the upper byte of its destination alone, while a 16-bit one is going to change it. The follow-up architecture, the ColdFire Eries of CPUs, has done away with these byte-sized instructions. Also be aware that 8-bit instructions set the flags according to these 8 bits only, while when replacing them with 16-bit operations it can be a nuisance to find the carry in the upper byte of the destination....

So, are you asking, instead of byte instructions, why not always use word instructions for ORIng, ANDing, EORing bits as they should be equal?

@Justme Basically, yes, that's a big part of my question. But I think the question extends to all immediate mode instructions actually, not just and/or/eor.

Apparently the designers felt that orthogonality was important and did so in having things work roughly the same for byte/word/long sizes.  As  you note, kind of CISCy; surely could have been done differently.  Later RISCy architectures eliminated all of the partial register ALU & logic operations (and overlapping register size aliases), keeping byte/(half)word operations only for load&store.

@ErikEidt a CISC CPU being orthogonal and CISCy — especially the MC68k — shouldn’t come as a giant surprise.

The CPU instruction set allows the user to use 8-bit bytes as shortest possible data type, instead of forcing to use 16-bit words as the shortest possible data type for doing operations.
For example ANDI instruction, the .B version only affects the low 8 bits. If you don't have .B but only .W version, then you yourself as the programmer or the compiler has to take into account, that if you really want to affect only the low 8 bits, the 16-bit immediate must have all high bits high in order to not affect the high 8 bits. And the flags don't resemble the 8-bit result for byte being zero or negative etc, but the whole 16-bit result.
Also if you want to add 8-bit quantities together with ADDI, how to update the flags after the addition is different if the operation is performed as 8-bit or 16-bit operation, as you might want to have an 8-bit result with carry, negative etc related to 8-bit operations instead of only working with 16-bit operations.

Pointing at the differences in flag evaluation is the best reason, great answer!

Seems obvious now that I think about it.

Yes, it's already a difference on logical level, but equally on program flow hardware.

Why? Compactness of Code!
Any CPU without will have to execute several instructions (masking / extraction / insertion) to perform the same. Byte immediates thus save a lot of code, especially in character handling .. at least back then (*1), making the CPU more useful - not just in Assembly but any language.
Also, Space for encoding that behaviour is already reserved by having an immediate with word/long-word - so nothing to save by not adding it.

Also: Byte Handling in General is Essential, Different and Useful
Byte handling would be incomplete without immediate - especially if that is given for all other basic data types.
Essential:

A CPU without will have to execute several instructions (masking/extraction/insertion) to do the same on a logical level.

On hardware level not having byte handling put severe restriction on I/O design.


Different:

Many byte operations can not be extended to word or longer without side effects.

This is especially true for when extending at compile time.

Even if extendable the results won't be the same.


Useful:

Having byte immediate compacts code, as it saves a use of additional instructions to handle immediate as data before using or additional data and address words.

The Fine Print

Byte is essential for Software:

Character handling is (*1) in real world applications a very important, if not the most important data type. Having an immediate mode is thus important for code density.
Not having immediate instructions would mean the need to hold in a register or memory cell, which means either another instruction to load that register with that immediate, or an Address register or lengthen the instruction with a relative word or absolute address long.


Byte is Essential for Hardware:

While RAM is (mostly) uniform, memory mapped I/O isn't.
RAM access width (*2) isn't really relevant
I/O access with is important and must therefor be controllable


The hardware needs to know that it's a byte operation to

select (mask) either byte of a word, letting the other be unaffected
not throw an address error (*3) in case of an odd address (*4)
limit memory access to always a single cycle, otherwise a byte at odd address may fetch two words.
limit read access to only that byte (*5) to prevent side effects with the other byte(s) within that word/longword
limit write (back) to that byte only, not touching any other


Next, on logical level (*6), byte operation can not be replaced by word operations without side effect:

It may seem easy to extend byte integers to word (*7,*8), but doing so may cause a series of side effects:

Over/Underflow into other bytes
Different result signalling (flags)


AND/OR immediates look like easy to be filed with all-one/all-zero to be turned into word/longword without touching the direct result, but

they may still deliver a different signalling (*9)


XOR and MOVE can not be extended, as it would require the knowledge of the content of all other bytes, usually not given at compile time (*7).


Last, there are no savings possible with the 68k's very school book like simple decoding structure:

It's word instruction format requires a full word for any constant smaller than a word.
Being quite regular CPU means the marker for byte operation is already there (S=00), so not using it for byte immediate would not save anything
Adding a secondary instruction format with 8 bit constant would complicate the structure




Conclusion
Byte access must be marked as such and immediate constants treated accordingly. All of the above prohibits any use of 16 bit constants with bytes without marking them as such, which the 68k already does. Extending shorter constants to 8 bits is as well not possible, except for the very restricted ADDQ/SUBQ case.
The mentioned immediate to SR and CR operations are rather the exception to prove the rule. They are fitted into otherwise unused combinations for those distinguished by byte (S=00) for CR and word (S=01) for SR. IMHO one of the more elegant solutions the 68k provides, allowing either register to be handled bitwise without prior extraction and insertion like many other CPU require.
And yes, this results in a whole byte 'wasted' in code when handling byte values, nicely showing another facet why the 68k lost to x86

A Side Note
You're clearly onto one of the major problems with the 68k: Code density.
The 68k forgives a lot of possible compactness for using a single instruction scheme (*10). One could have thought about some additional formats, like squeezing in single bit instructions. In the end the word structure prevents any relevant saving by restricting instructions to 2/4/6/8 bytes, but not inbetween.
x86 on the other hand with its byte structured instructions allow any instruction length, already starting at a single byte (*11). The equivalent of an ANDI is just 3 bytes instead of 4. In addition the less regular structure with lots of (overwritable) defaults  especially segmented addressing also helped quite a lot. All of this adds pay out, resulting in an almost RLL like encoding making x86 programs in general shorter (*12) and thus by design faster than 68k (*13).
Yes, code size is an important factor in performance but often forgotten. Each and every instruction going thru the same memory interface as data will reduce data thruput. Quite extreme back in the days of synchronous CPUs and still relevant with all the megabytes of cache today.
So if one intends to program Assembly only, then the 68k is a clearer, rather simple and straight forward choice. In al other cases x86 will be of advantage.

*1 - It was at least until the advent of 16/32 bit character codes, which the 68k design predates.
*2 - That is if the RAM is accessed at once thru an 8, 16, 32, 64 or whatever wide data bus or multiple or parts thereof.
*3 - The original 68k could not access unaligned data.
*4 - About half the time when processing character data.
*5 - That's why the CPU has UDS/LDS instead of just A0
*6 - Programmers tend to look first at logical operation, then (if at all) onto hardware, hardware designers work the other way around.
*7 - Only compile time is relevant, as execution time adjustment is already what the size field does.
*8 - ADDQ/SUBQ does not extend but fill up with zero that's why two instructions are needed.
*9 - Imagine a byte value of $00 and a register value of $1234. Used for ANDing one expects the zero flag to be set - after all, and with all-zero always returns zero, right? Well, having $00 extended by all-one to make preserve all other bytes gives $FF00. ANDing that to $1234 results in $1200. A result clearly not all-zero, which the cleared zero flag will show :)
*10 - Notably without saving anything in memory interface (pinout/protocol) and only little in instruction fetch/provisioning.
*11 - Not perfect since the selection of single byte codes were not made for occurrence but in relation to 8080 encoding. While this often resulted in common opcodes being shorter, it also wasted some of those precious resources.
*12 - We talk useful code, not interface or OS bloat.
*13 - not to mention that the implementation of variable length encoding enabled, if not required, independent execution of instruction fetch, keeping memory utilisation at a maximum, whereas the 68k with it's strict synchronous design could not use all memory access possible. All with less effort (transistors), faster to market and lower price :))

For many tasks, an instruction to add an 8-bit or 16-bit value from memory to a full-sized register with sign-extension or zero extension would have been more useful than having instructions only affect the bottom 8 or 16 bits of a register, if all operations would take the same amount of time.  The fact that the 68000 can't efficiently handle carry propagation through the top half of a 32-bit word makes it necessary to have a lot of operands only act on the bottom 16 bits of a register, and treating byte operations similarly would be less odd than extending to just 16 bits.

Code density: In theory, yes, the 8086 was better, as you say. In practice, it rarely was - The complex adressing modes supported by the m68k did a lot to level out x86 advantages in real-life programs.

There are enough "real" oddities in the m68k: Why, for example, is there a specific CLR instruction, when SUB or MOVE # is almost always faster? Why did "base+index" addressing only allow byte offsets (at least at first)? Why does MOVE to an address register sign extend, to a data register it doesn't, but MOVEM sign extends to both?

@tofro Real life compiler do not use most complex addressing modes and even with, x86 did win in all cases I know. Real world, not synthetic picked. CLR is for mem where it needs less code than MOVE or SUB. You mean (d8+Dn+An) when saying base+index? It's because the extension word has only 8 bit left for index (again that word size instruction issue - here x86 can always do 8 or 16). MOVE word is a 16 bit operation, while MOVE word to An is a signed because of relative addressing. MOVE EM must use one way for both (so signed it is). I wouldn't consider any of that as oddity.

@tofro For CLR, the speed difference is due to CLR being implemented as RMW - yes, it really ready the data to be cleared first before writing all zero. So it's gain is really all about code size by saving the constant a MOVE #imm would need.

I wasn't relating to code density in compiled programs - The m68k series always lacked (and even lacks today) a compiler that could actually use its features (One of the insights that lead to the ColdFire architecture).

@tofro The majority of all software is compiled (as in from some way too primitive HLL). This also hits x86 leaving great features unused. And code density is direct related to performance. Every memory slot not used to read code is one available to handle data. In fact, that relation is usually more relevant than having'powerful' instructions or addressing modes.

@Raffzahn: People like to complain about 16-bit x86 segmentation, but SI+of16 mode is often used for things like array accesses; while the 68000 supports an AReg+ofs16 mode, it would only really be useful for applying an index to a statically-allocated array if the array in question was in the first or last 32K of address space.  The DS register plays a role very similar to what A5 is used for on the Macintosh, but one can add two more registers and a 16 bit constant in addition to it.
